# How to get configuration file for Google Analytics if I am NOT Admin of the account?

Tags: android, google-analytics, configuration-files, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to get a configuration file from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).
When I click the button `GET A CONFIGURATION FILE`, I am not able to select an application.

I am not the admin of the account which created the applications but I have permissions to read.

Comment: Have the admin of the account get it for you?  BTW This is the project created on Google Developers console. This has nothing to do with Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is very confusing there. This has nothing to do with Google Analytics.   The App you need to select was one that was created in [Google Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0).   This has nothing to do with your access to the Google Analytics account.

I have contacted Google about fixing the bug.